# Getting NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet to work with a custom date format

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, nodatime

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON, which contains dates in the format `2017-10-26 13:32:11 Etc/GMT`. [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org) seems to support this when combined with [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and [NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet/). I found some info here on StackOverflow that made me get this working, using only NodaTime:

```
var date = "2017-10-26 13:32:11 Etc/GMT";

var pattern = ZonedDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture(
    "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss z", 
    DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb
);

var result = pattern.Parse(date);
```

However when extending this example into deserializing a JSON using the other two packages, I can't get it to work. From reading documentation and other resources, I believe this is supposed to work:

```
public class DateObj
{
    public ZonedDateTime Date { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var date = "2017-10-26 13:32:11 Etc/GMT";
    var json = $"{{\"Date\": \"{date}\"}}";

    var pattern = ZonedDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture(
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z",
        DateTimeZoneProviders.Serialization
    );

    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.ConfigureForNodaTime(pattern.ZoneProvider);
    var dateObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateObj>(json, settings);
}
```

But it throws an exception on the last line saying `The value string does not match a quoted string in the pattern. Value being parsed: '2017-10-26^ 13:32:11 Etc/GMT'. (^ indicates error position.)`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have to use `DateTimeOffset` rather than the Noda Time `OffsetDateTime` type? In general, life's simpler if you can stick to Noda Time types entirely.

Comment: No, I can use any type, but there is not much difference, I only get another error; `The value string does not match a quoted string in the pattern. Value being parsed: '2017-10-26^ 13:32:11 Etc/GMT'. (^ indicates error position.)`. Tried with a few different variants of the pattern, without `'` etc, and with a few different types, `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`, but the error remained the same.

Comment: If you're happy to make the value a `ZonedDateTime`, you should be able to get it to work. (When I suggested `OffsetDateTime` I hadn't spotted that actually your value contains a time zone, not an offset.) At the moment, the question isn't about that approach - it would probably be worth either deleting your current answer and changing the question to be about "Getting NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet to work with a custom format" or creating a new question for that. I definitely want to help either way though...

Comment: Question updated :)

Comment: Great, thanks. Will work on it now.

Comment: how ur able to convert dates as per timezone. i am also looking for similar issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, you're creating a specific `ZonedDateTime` pattern - but you're not actually telling Json.NET about that pattern anywhere.

If this is the *only* Noda Time type that you need to use, I'd advise that you don't call `ConfigureForNodaTime` at all - because that will configure a `ZonedDateTime` converter with the wrong pattern. We have [code internal to NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime.serialization/blob/edf88349e54ab63f06266a9c864edfa1ba6503cb/src/NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet/Extensions.cs#L148) to replace a converter, but that's not exposed at the moment. (Maybe we should do that...)

It's simple to just create a single converter though, and configure the settings for that:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
    Converters = { new NodaPatternConverter<ZonedDateTime>(pattern) }
};
```

Here's what that looks like in the context of a full program. Note that I'm explicitly using `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb` here, rather than `DateTimeZoneProviders.Serialization`, given that you definitely have TZDB identifiers:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet;
using NodaTime.Text;
using System;

public class DateObj
{
    public ZonedDateTime Date { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var date = "2017-10-26 13:32:11 Etc/GMT";
        var json = $"{{\"Date\": \"{date}\"}}";

        var pattern = ZonedDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z",
            DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb
        );

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters = { new NodaPatternConverter<ZonedDateTime>(pattern) }
        };
        var dateObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateObj>(json, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(dateObj.Date);
    }
}
```

Comment: public static JsonSerializerSettings ConfiguredForNodaTime(this JsonSerializerSettings settings, IDateTimeZoneProvider provider)
        {

            LocalDatePattern pattern = LocalDatePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture(
            "dd-MMM-yyyy");

            AddToDefaultConverters(settings.Converters, provider,pattern);
            settings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
            return settings;
        }

Comment: @stephenebichondo: I'm not quite sure of the point of your comment. Could you clarify please?